# How do I send the profile data to a client page after authentication with Google OAuth?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js

So, this is my server side code where I handle my routes:

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const passport = require("./auth");
const path = require("path");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
app.use(
    session({
        secret: A Secret,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/webpages/CurrentProjects"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/webpages/codingspace"));
app.use("/socket.io",express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist")
);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("webpages"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    req.user ? next() : res.sendStatus(401);
}
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })
);
app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/auth/failure" }),
    (req, res) => {
        // Successful authentication, redirect to currentProjects.html
        res.redirect("/home");
    }
);
app.get("/home", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/webpages/CurrentProjects/currentProjects.html");
});
app.get("/auth/failure", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Wrong credentials!");
});
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.send("Goodbye!");
    console.log("User logged out");
});
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and this is my auth.js where I handle OAuth:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID:"something",
            clientSecret: "something",
            callbackURL: "something",
            profileURL: "something",
        },
        (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            console.log("Passport Callback Function Started");
            console.log(profile);
            return done(null, "/home");
        }
    )
);
passport.serializeUser(function (profile, done) {
    done(null, profile);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});
module.exports = passport;
```

Is there any way by which I can send the profile data I got in auth.js to a client side page like index.html?

I tried both localstorage and cookies but cookies failed because I was using EJS for half the code and CJS for half the code(Stupid, ik) and localstorage didn't work because for some reason the server responded with and error when I tried to write the profile data to localstorage.